# Hibernate-Component class not found

Tags: java, hibernate

I don't understand what is going on here. This is the exception I'm getting:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/demoBancoWeb/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.edu.icesi.demo.modelo.ConsignacionesId
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getComponentClass(Component.java:138)
    ... 42 more
```

The first block of stack trace is the Hibernate exception and the second block of trace is the relation with my classes.

**That class, ConsignacionesId was automatically generated by Hibernate as a multi-attribute ID.**

This is my hibernate cfg.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/banco</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <mapping resource="co/edu/icesi/demo/modelo/Clientes.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="co/edu/icesi/demo/modelo/Cuentas.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="co/edu/icesi/demo/modelo/TiposUsuarios.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="co/edu/icesi/demo/modelo/TiposDocumentos.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="co/edu/icesi/demo/modelo/Consignaciones.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="co/edu/icesi/demo/modelo/Usuarios.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="co/edu/icesi/demo/modelo/Retiros.hbm.xml"/>

    <mapping resource="co/edu/icesi/demo/modelo/Consultas.hbm.xml"/>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And finally, this are my classes generated by Hibernate:

[image]

**As you can see, ConsignacionesId IS there.**
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Has all your classes compiled properly?

Comment: Yes, they did. I found a solution but it doesn't seem very lasting. I added the "modelo" Class Folder to the buildpath and it worked. I have absolutely no idea why this happened.

Comment: check you post your full stack of exception?

Comment: No, I posted the initial exception and then the piece of stack trace containing the problem related to my classes. I skipped the internals of  Hibernate.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I was missing the complete path to my classes inside the hibernate hbm.xml files.

This:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <!-- Generated 01-feb-2016 18:51:34 by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0 -->
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="Clientes" table="clientes" schema="public">
            <id name="cliId" type="long">
                <column name="cli_id" precision="10" scale="0" />
                <generator class="assigned" />
            </id>
            <many-to-one name="tiposDocumentos" class=
.
.
.
```

Had to look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <!-- Generated 01-feb-2016 18:51:34 by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0 -->
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="co.edu.icesi.demo.modelo.Clientes" table="clientes" schema="public">
            <id name="cliId" type="long">
                <column name="cli_id" precision="10" scale="0" />
                <generator class="assigned" />
            </id>
            <many-to-one name="tiposDocumentos" class="

.
.
.
```

So I just pasted "co.edu.icesi.demo.modelo." before all my generated classes, and it worked.

I hope this helps somebody.

This happened because in the "Hibernate Code Generation Cofigurations..." I DID NOT use the field "package".

The "destiny" folder should be only src/main/java.

Don't create the package that will hold your generated classes by yourself. In my case, don't create **co.edu.icesi.demo.modelo**.

That path goes inside the "package" field of "Hibernate Code Generation Configurations..."